# What is an appropriate filament to 3D print a replacement microwave turntable ring?

Tags: filament-choice, heat

I recently had the unfortunate experience of someone in my household accidentally breaking the microwave turntable ring. Considering the replacement cost of a new tray ring is upwards of $70, I'm exploring the option of 3D printing a replacement. However, I'm not sure which 3D printing material would be best suited for this task. Here are some key points to consider:

- I'm aware that certain 3D printers are limited in terms of filament compatibility, but fortunately, I own a Bambu Lab X1 Carbon that supports a wide range of filament types.
- Given the cost of the replacement part, affordability is a factor. I'd prefer a material that comes in at a lower price point than $70.
- Durability and heat resistance are crucial factors since the replacement part will be used in a microwave.

With these considerations in mind, could anyone recommend the most suitable 3D printing material for crafting a sturdy and heat-resistant replacement microwave turntable ring using the capabilities of a Bambu Lab X1 Carbon printer? Your insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Polypropylene .

Comment: What was the original made from? Did it have a recycling symbol, or does the replacement's website say?

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine it doesn't have a recycling symbol on it. None of the replacement parts specify what material it's made of.

Comment: I just came across another site which said:
PPS+GF40%,V0,XP. I believe PPS is polyphenylene sulfide but I'm not quite sure what the other information means or if it's even relevant.

Comment: @PeteK68 GF ususally means glass fibre.

Comment: According to multiple sources on the internet, PP is considered microwave safe and that's what most "microwave safe" plastic containers are made of.

But that's not the entire story. The best way to figure out if a material will deteriorate in microwave is, well .... microwave it :) If it survives prolonged exposure it's unlikely to have a problem as a mechanical part as it's not in contact with food.

Comment: Here are few Thingiverse models with claims (either by author or in makes) of being made from "good old" PLA.

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1418362
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2460702

Here's one using ABS
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:385288

How safe it is? Who knows.

Comment: @Griffin That seems like a short answer, please post a more elaborate version as an actual answer!